# Write stream of data in a row in a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

i have to create a text file having four rows,in each rows there will be two hundred zeros.If i create a loop and  write it will take more time.How can i print stream of data in single loop.i used this code

```
        for (int j = 0; j <= 599; j++)
            {
                if (j >= 0 && j <= 199)
                {
                    if (j == 199)
                        writer.WriteLine("0");
                    else
                        writer.Write("0");
                }
                else if (j >= 200 && j <= 399)
                {
                    if (j == 499)
                        writer.WriteLine("0");
                    else
                        writer.Write("0");
                }
                else if (j >= 400 && j <= 599)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: What makes you think two loops would take more time?

Comment: Your code prints only 300 zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a "constant" first:

```
string line = new String('0', 200);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: string line = new String("0", 200);

Comment: require to pass char and int as parameters

Comment: @ranjenanil You can check now

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, thank you. Did not notice the double quotes.